# How to transfer data using MultipeerConnectivity?

Tags: ios, swift, archive, multipeer-connectivity, mpmediaitem

I'm trying to transfer an array of MPMediaItem(s) to another device using MultipeerConnectivity, so I can show a list (TableView) of songs and therefore remote control the peer.

This piece of code encodes my music library items so I can send them to another peer.

```
func encodeLibrary(lib: [MPMediaItem]) -> NSData {
    print("before encoding: \(lib.count)")
    // --> prints "before encoding: 511"

    let data = NSMutableData()

    let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver.init(forWritingWithMutableData: data)
    archiver.encodeObject(lib, forKey: "data")
    archiver.finishEncoding()

    let unarchiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver.init(forReadingWithData: data)
    let newLib = unarchiver.decodeObjectForKey("data") as! [MPMediaItem]

    print("decoded: \(newLib.count)")
    // --> prints "decoded: 511"

    return data
}
```

The following code is then executed on another peer:

```
func decodeLibrary(data: NSData) -> [MPMediaItem] {

    let unarchiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver.init(forReadingWithData: data)
    let lib = unarchiver.decodeObjectForKey("data") as! [MPMediaItem]

    print("items: \(lib.count)")
    //prints "items: 0"

    return lib
}
```

To send the data I use the following call:

```
try! session.sendData(data, toPeers: [peerID], withMode: .Reliable)
```

It's not a problem with the en-/decoding because it works when i run the decoding on the same device right after the encoding as you can see. It prints 511 songs before and after.
There has to be a problem while being transmitted or anything I can't think of why.
When data arrives on another device, everything except these MPMediaItems is available as well.

I do not receive any errors and other parts of the communication are working fine. Just this one array does not seem to be available on other devices. Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks in advance,
KlixxOne

EDIT: Actually the array is there, but it has no content (which it had on the other device (511 entries)).

Comment: What is the value of `data.length` on both sides?

Comment: its 22469 on both sides. its equal :( isn't it weird?